# Rendering an obj model to an image server side using nodejs and threejs

Tags: node.js, three.js, server-side-rendering

I have already got the code set to render a blue cube and export it to an image, however, my issue is getting it to load an obj model.

```
const gl = require('gl')(1920, 1080, { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
const THREE = require('three');
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;
const { OBJLoader } = require('oopanda-three-obj-mtl-loader');
const fs = require('fs');

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;


const width = 1920;
const height = 1080;
const path = 'output.png';
const png = new PNG({ width: width, height: height });

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ context: gl });

const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const cubeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `
    void main() {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec4 solidColor;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = solidColor;
    }
  `,
  uniforms: {
    solidColor: { type: 'v4', value: new THREE.Vector4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) }, // Red color
  },
});

const cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
// Set the camera position
camera.position.set(5, 1, 1);

// Set the focal point
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
scene.add(cube);

function animate() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // Read back the pixel data
  const gl = renderer.getContext();
  const pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * width * height);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

  // Process and save pixel data as PNG
  for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      const k = j * width + i;
      const r = pixels[4 * k];
      const g = pixels[4 * k + 1];
      const b = pixels[4 * k + 2];
      const a = pixels[4 * k + 3];

      // Flip and convert to PNG format
      const m = (height - j - 1) * width + i;
      png.data[4 * m] = r;
      png.data[4 * m + 1] = g;
      png.data[4 * m + 2] = b;
      png.data[4 * m + 3] = a;
    }
  }

  // Write the PNG to disk
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  png.pack().pipe(stream);

  stream.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`Image written: ${path}`);
  });
}

// Call animate to render and save the image
animate();
```

I have tried using node modules like "oopanda-three-obj-mtl-loader" however I keep getting cast with errors such as

```
B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\node_modules\three\build\three.cjs:28601
                const req = new Request(url, {
                            ^

ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at FileLoader.load (B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\node_modules\three\build\three.cjs:28601:15)
    at OBJLoader.load (B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\node_modules\three-obj-mtl-loader\index.js:945:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\index.js:53:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

and

```
B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\node_modules\three\build\three.cjs:28602
                        headers: new Headers(this.requestHeader),
                                     ^

ReferenceError: Headers is not defined
    at FileLoader.load (B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\node_modules\three\build\three.cjs:28602:17)
    at OBJLoader.load (B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\node_modules\three-obj-mtl-loader\index.js:945:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\cd\6780d7cc0cabb1b4d6c8\index.js:59:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering suggests that the `Request` and `Headers` objects are not defined. These objects are typically available in browser environments but not in Node.js by default. To load an OBJ model using `three-obj-mtl-loader` in a Node.js environment, you'll need to make a few adjustments.

Here's a modified version of your code that demonstrates how to load an OBJ model in a Node.js environment using `three-obj-mtl-loader` and save it as an image:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { createCanvas } = require('canvas');
const { WebGLRenderer, Scene, PerspectiveCamera, BoxGeometry, Mesh, Vector3 } = require('three');
const { OBJLoader } = require('three-obj-mtl-loader');

const width = 1920;
const height = 1080;
const path = 'output.png';

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ canvas });

const scene = new Scene();
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);

camera.position.set(5, 1, 5);
camera.lookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

const cubeGeometry = new BoxGeometry();
const cubeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `
    void main() {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec4 solidColor;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = solidColor;
    }
  `,
  uniforms: {
    solidColor: { type: 'v4', value: new Vector4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) }, // Blue color
  },
});

const cube = new Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
scene.add(cube);

const loader = new OBJLoader();

loader.load('path/to/your/model.obj', (obj) => {
  // Adjust the position, scale, or rotation of your loaded OBJ model if needed
  obj.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  obj.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  scene.add(obj);

  // Render the scene
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // Save the rendered image as a PNG file
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  const pngStream = canvas.createPNGStream();

  pngStream.pipe(stream);

  stream.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`Image written: ${path}`);
  });
});
```

In this code, we use the `createCanvas` function from the `canvas` package to create a canvas element compatible with Node.js. We also modify the code to load your OBJ model using `three-obj-mtl-loader`. Adjust the model's position, scale, or rotation as needed before rendering and saving the image as a PNG file.

Make sure to replace 'path/to/your/model.obj' with the actual path to your OBJ model file. This code should work in a Node.js environment without requiring the `Request` and `Headers` objects.